# Working out percentages of a column in a table

Tags: python

I have been struggling all day trying to automatically insert percentages into a table
The table I have in mind is this:

```
    Variable            Category    Number
    Cardiovascular_Dx   No          161
                        Yes         42
                        Non-missing 203
              IHD_Dx    No          192
                        Yes         11
                        Non-missing 203
```

I want to have the no's and yes's as percentages of non-missing. Eventually I am looking to place it in a format:

```
    Variable            Category    Number(%)
    Cardiovascular_Dx   No          161 (79%)
                        Yes         42  (21%)
                        Non-missing 203 
              IHD_Dx    No          192  (95%)
                        Yes         11   (5%)
                        Non-missing 203
```

I realise this can be easy in Excel, but I have been looking for a pythonic way to do it. I have been looping through, but the problem is that the non missing is looped through last so I cannot simply store the value, divide by non missing[2] then reinsert the row.
If anyone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: Why not loop through twice?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the data structure you're using - looks like a pandas table? Either way, if you want to do it in a single pass have you thought about looping backwards instead? That way you'll have the non-missing count before you hit the Yes/No.

Answer (score 0):

Loop once, calculate the Total, Loop Twice, calculate the percentage based on total in Loop 1.

Answer (score 0):

Loop backwards so you have the total before hitting the Yes/No.